# What is the need of Privileged Block in Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, privileges

I have seen code to get field value through Reflection executed within Privilege block. Following piece of code is taken from [`ReflectionUtil`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/common/util/ReflectionUtil.java):

```
public static <T> T accessDeclaredField(final Field f, final Object o, final Class<T> responseClass) {
    return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<T>() {
        public T run() {
            boolean b = f.isAccessible();
            try {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                return responseClass.cast(f.get(o));
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                return null;
            } finally {
                f.setAccessible(b);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I don't understand the reason to get the field value within the privileged block; we can do it without of it.

Is it better coding practice or do we gain something extra?

Ref: [API for Privileged Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/doprivileged.html)

Comment: As an unrleated side note: If anyone's security settings load CXF as trusted code and some untrusted code as well, the untrusted code can (by just calling this `public static` method with right parameters) escape out of the Java sandbox. Which parameters is left as an exercise to the reader. Lesson learned: Never use doPrivileged in a **public** method where the caller can control all relevant parameters...

Comment: @mihi Your comment would teach many more people if it didn't leave out the key piece of the puzzle as an excercise to the reader. For most people there will be "no lessons learned".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik for most people it is enough to know you can write to any private fields, and that this is a security problem. Finding the ones to write to to break the security manager is not that hard. For inspiration: https://github.com/schierlm/JavaPayload/blob/master/JavaPayload/src/javapayload/escalate/EscalateBasics.java#L58

Comment: @mihi Write? I don't see any writing in there... I actually thought you had some cool side-effect in mind, such as class init, AOP-advised field getting or similar.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ok you are right, it is probably not so obvious. The method calls `setAccessible` on a field instance provided by the caller, which means that in the time window until it sets it back, another thread can use the field instance to write to the field. And even if the chance looks small to you, two threads that repeatedly try to call the method and set the field will usually succeed after less than one second...

Comment: @mihi Ah, now we're talking... I've always had an issue with the stateful `accessible` API. I really don't see any benefit to it and security issues abound.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I guess it grew historically (`setAccessible` was added in 1.2) and they did not want to re-engineer the whole reflection API...

Comment: @mihi Yes, I can clearly imagine how it came about... but still, I'd say it lacks thinking through and better solutions were available even for Java 1.2. For example, just like `PrivilegedAction` API, but for a block of code within which no access checks are done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without an installed Security Manager you don't need a privileged block. However, if you are writing fully general library code, which may be executed with a security manager in place, and the caller of the library may not have the needed permissions, then without a `PrivilegedAction` your code will be denied access as well, even though the code on its own (its CodeSource) does have the permission.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you gain the benefit of calling the `PrivilegedAction` with the permissions of the calling class, even if the code (in this case the method `accessDeclaredField`) is called by an outside code that does not have these permissions.

Without using `AccessController.doPrivileged`, then if some code X calls the `ReflectionUtils` API to access a declared field and code X does not have the security permission `suppressAccessChecks` then the action will fail with a security exception.

By wrapping the action inside a `AccessController.doPrivileged`, `ReflectionUtils` marks that its action should be executed with its *own* permissions even if the calling code X does not have those permissions.